# How to prevent data change from "&" to "&amp" after using .marshal().jacksonxml() in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm having a problem after marshaling data from db to xml using

```
.marshal().jacksonxml(false)
```

in Apache Camel. In my data from db, there are "&" , which should not be changed to  `"&amp;"`  after marshaling to xml
AND `"&amp;"` , which is okay jsut as it is..
Since I have two cases in my data, I can't just use

```
.transform(new Expression() {
@Override
public <T> T evaluate(Exchange exchange, Class<T> type) {
String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
body = body.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");}
```

after marshaling.
Do you know any option to solve this problem in Camel or any suggestions?

Comment: What you are saying isn't logical. Any `&` should be encoded as `&amp;` in XML, and `&amp;` has to become `&amp;amp;`. Once the data is read from the XML document again later on, these will turn back to `&` and `&amp;` just fine.

Comment: thanks for the comment! some of my data are stored as xml format already like `<ARTICLE title="3.&amp;nbsp;>` and it is not changed to  `&amp;amp; ` after mashaling..

Comment: i just checked it again and you are right! `&amp;` becomes `&amp;amp;`! thanks!